# multi-word search mongoose

Tags: mongodb, search, mongoose

in mongodb api:-

```
db.articles.runCommand( "text", { search: "bake coffee cake" } )
```

allows for multiple words to be searched at once, in mongodb document.

What is the correponding command in mongoosejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the most integrated experience in Mongoose, I'd suggest you have a look at one of the Mongoose author's Mongoose extensions:

https://github.com/aheckmann/mongoose-text-search

It adds support for the still-experimental text-search feature of MongoDB.

Answer (score 2):

Mongodb ver 2.6 has introduced **$text** query operator. It performs a text search on the content of the fields indexed with a [text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/). You can use it from Mongoose like this:

```
Article.find(
    { $text : { $search : "bake coffee cake"} }
).exec(callback);
```

Comment: I gave done exactly that but it is not working. Loosing my mind over this. Full question on my page. If you have a minute to have a look, that will be great